# Cannot connect to MySQL database on GoDaddy

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been trying to connect to my database but can't connect.
Just 3 days ago I purchased domain and hosting plan on GoDaddy.
First thing I did was I downloaded my database from another account and tried
to import to my new account. It gave me an error that database was not found to upload my table. So I created new database using GoDaddy's cPanel which allows us to create databases. Then I created users and added privileges to them. It clearly shows, in the below pictures, that user was created and added to database. But when I try to connect to my database by PHP script using pdo connection, it throw the below error.

---

```
[06-Aug-2018 06:15:17 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'cajetanF'@'ip-160-153-129-239.ip.secureserver.net' (using password: YES) in /home/ry91p8weag4x/public_html/Conn.php:9
Stack trace:
# 0 /home/ry91p8weag4x/public_html/Conn.php(9): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=sgva...', 'cajetanF', 'Cajetan')
# 1 {main}
  thrown in /home/ry91p8weag4x/public_html/Conn.php on line 9
```

I am attached pictures below of the database.
There is an auto user given my phpMyAdmin I guess who has full access
but I just can't understand how to connect using that,
I tried connecting with that user but can't.
I just want to know what might be the password for that account to connect to my database.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show us your connection class.

Comment: Hi, here is my connection.... $host   = "example.com";
    $db     = "sgItems";
    $user   = "cajetanF";
    $pass   = "xxx";
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  note: example.com is just used to hide the actual domain name. its using ssl (https:) so i am not sure if i have to do something else in my connection file to connect to ssl sites

Comment: The only thing in my mind comes, use localhost instead of domain name. Except that, your code seems ok.

Comment: bingo!!!! problem solved. Thank you Ashickur Rahman. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Your GRANT is giving permission to the user@**localhost** but the error message is telling you that they are @**ip-160-153-129-239.ip.secureserver.net**.

You have to give permission for the user to connect from the place they are connecting from.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i am really having hard time to get this done. Please advise how or from where i have to give permission. so are your telling me that i should connect with pdo with username "localhost" and server "ip-160-153-129-239.ip.secureserver.net"?

Comment: No. You've given permission to `you@A` but you are really `you@B`. GRANT permission to `you@B`.

Comment: Thank you Quentin. solved the error. i had to replace domain name with localhost. Thank you for you help as well.